# Subscribing to remote rospy publisher

Tags: java, ros, rospy

I implemented publish/subscribe using rosjava as subscriber and rospy as publisher. However, I do not receive any message from rospy. Did I miss anything here?

SUBSCRIBER IN JAVA (say ip is: 1.1.1.1)

```
public void start_on_init() {
   nodeConfiguration = NodeConfiguration.newPublic("1.1.1.1");
   nodeConfiguration.setMasterUri(new URI("http://localhost:11311/"));
   NodeMain listener = new SampleProcessor();
   NodeMainExecutor nodeMainExecutor = DefaultNodeMainExecutor.newDefault();
   nodeMainExecutor.execute(listener, nodeConfiguration);
}

class SampleProcessor extends AbstractNodeMain {
   ...
   public void onStart(ConnectedNode connectedNode) {
      Subscriber<std_msgs.String> subscriber = connectedNode.newSubscriber("sample_topic", std_msgs.String._TYPE);
      subscriber.addMessageListener(new MessageListener<std_msgs.String>() {
         @Override
         public void onNewMessage(std_msgs.String message) {
            logger.info(message.getData());
   ...
```

PUBLISHER IN PYTHON (say ip is: 1.1.1.2)

```
sample_publisher = rospy.Publisher("sample_topic", String , queue_size=10)
sample_publisher.publish(some_json_data)
```

Exported master uri as env variable before running python script using shell script

```
export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://1.1.1.1:11311
```

Answer (score -1):

I think there is only chance that nodes are not in same space.
Where is roscore running? Is master machine IP exported as ROS_MASTER_URI on slave machine? I think you should hardly study network setup in ROS [here](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/MultipleMachines)